# What is a named object?

Tags: c++

When talking about Return Value Optimisation (RVO), various texts mention exception cases related to the return of Named Objects. So in short:

- What are they?
- Is there a definition for this term in the current c++ standard?

Side note: I've tried to add the following tags: RVO and NRVO but due to lack of reputation points I wasn't able to take this post correctly

Answer (score 5):

A named object is just like it sounds:

```
  someclass foo() {
    someclass foo;
    foo.member = 42;
    return foo;
  }
```

As opposed to:

```
  someclass foo() {
    return someclass(42);
  }
```

The latter case is simple to optimize.